# Groupby or pivot in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Can someone guide me on aggregating data in pandas?

I have a massive file with per timestamp survey data from about thousands of different people and over 20 different locations. Each survey has a four levels of 'Reasons' which I have listed as Driver1, Driver2 (there are 4). Then there is a column which counts the surveys and a few columns for each question. Since each row of the raw data is an individual survey, the count is always 1 and the score can either be -1,0,1.

```
       Date        Location    Person  Driver1  Driver2  Surveys   Question1   
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 4/30/2014 21:41    a123b      xyz234   Quest    Ion       1         -1
```

---

My goal is to:

- Create a new raw data by aggregating the daily total surveys (sum) and mean scores per question
- This should be a a daily (no timestamp) level per location and per person and per driver (4 levels)

  ```
       Date    Location   Person  Driver1  Driver2  Surveys   Question1   
  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
   4/30/2014    a123b     xyz234   Quest    Ion       3        0.33
   4/30/2014    a123b     xyz234   Quest    Bear      6         1
  ```

  ---

This will vastly reduce the file size but still give me detailed data. I want to know the performance of each person for survey drivers per day so I can track monthly/weekly progress.

I assume it must be something like:

```
df2 = df.groupby['Date','Location','Person','Driver1','Driver2','Driver3','Driver4']
df2['Surveys'].sum()
df2['Question1'].mean()
```

Comment: did actually you try that? the groupby syntax is `df.groupby(by=list_of_columns)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close.  You need some () around that groupby

```
df2 = df.groupby(['Date','Location','Person','Driver1','Driver2','Driver3','Driver4'])
```

Then you combine the next two lines into one if you'd like

```
df2.agg({'Surveys' : 'sum', 'Question1' : 'mean'})
```

Comment: Nice, this seems to work. I am running into an error though.

AttributeError: Cannot access callable attribute 'to_csv' of 'DataFrameGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method
----

I am trying to export these results to .csv. I am basically creating a new 'raw data' for my Tableau to connect to and to keep in Excel (which is what everyone uses in our company unfortunately). 
-----

When I use the groupby can I export those results into a new file post aggregation?

Comment: Lance, I'm not sure why you're getting that error.  I just did something very similar as a test and it had no problems.  What version of pandas are you using?

Comment: 0.14 currently.

This works:
df2 = df.groupby(['Date','Location','Person','Driver1','Driver2','Driver3','Driver4']).sum()
df2.reset_index()
df2.to_csv(r'C:\Users\file.csv')

This shows results as I would expect, but it doesn't allow me to reset index (I want each label to be repeated, think of an Excel file) or export to csv
df2.agg({'Surveys' : 'sum', 'Question1' : 'mean'})

I am getting the attribute error for some reason.

Comment: Regarding the indexes we can do this a couple of ways.  We can do this df2.reset_index(inplace=True) or you can pass as_index=False in your groupby.